# Linkedin POST Api - Get all posts

Tags: linkedin-api

We have some problems with the new linkedin APi. (Posts) specifically with  "Find Posts by Authors"

First:
We are not able to get all post.
Is only bringing some post and none of the last 6 months

Secondly: Is not bringing any value in pagination (is always empty).The only way we find to get another batch is changing the start parameter

Third:
The example is not working: this parameter  'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0'  makes the api fail

curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author={encoded organization urn like urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%32414183}&isDsc=false&q=author&count=10' 
-H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' 
-H 'LinkedIn-Version: {version number in the format YYYYMM}' 
-H 'X-RestLi-Method: FINDER' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}'

Can anyone give us some help, please?
Is anything we are doing weon

Thank you!
#linkedin
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-10&tabs=curl

Comment: Hi Pablo, 

Have also issues with the new post API. Following the example in the doc, I also get the #3 issue. But removing the X-Restli-Protocol-Version doesn't help anything. I get a 403 / ""Field Value validation failed in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/author]" error.

Wondering if you had encountered this during your test ? Any feedback from linkedin so far ?

Below is my request for reference (+ all the headers from the doc) 

'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%$5079938&isDsc=false&q=author&count=10'

Comment: Hi did you find a solution I know you should do both isDsc=false and isDsc=true to get more cases but even like this some are still missing