# Linkedin new Post API - 403 error / Field Value validation failed

Tags: linkedin-api

Trying to use the new POST API from linkedin, to get all the posts for an organization [described in the doc here](https://ttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-06&tabs=http#sample-request-2)

Both CURL and HTTP requests gives me a 403 with the following message `"Field Value validation failed in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/author]"`

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%$XXXXX&isDsc=false&q=author&count=10' \
-H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
-H 'LinkedIn-Version: 202210' \
-H 'X-RestLi-Method: FINDER' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}'
```

Tried to remove the X-Restli-Protocol-Version header [as per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74117132/linkedin-post-api-get-all-posts), but didn't help much.

Thanks in advance !